# When can we change a PDE to an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

When solving a PDE such as:
$$u_{xx} - u = 0$$
I know that we can treat it as an ODE and then the solution would be
$$u(x, y) = A(y)e^{−x} + B(y)e^x$$
where the functions A and B would have replaced the parameters of the solution of the ODE.

But why does this work, I just can't seem to grasp the idea behind it. Is there any intuitive way to think about why this works ?

Comment: It works because there are no $y$ derivatives in the equation, so the function $u(x,y)$ that satisfies the equation can be thought of as a function of $x$ and a parameter $y$.

Comment: @mattos I know that's when it works, but why though ?

Comment: Along each horizontal line i.e. by looking at $f(x)=u(x,y_0)$ you really do have an ODE, and the $y_0$ is just a parameter which can only change which solution to the ODE you select on that line.

Comment: @Ian why would different $_0$ not change the whole ODE solution, in other words can you please elaborate on why does it act like a parameter ?

Comment: Does it help to notice that (i) The solutions of $u'' = u$ are $u(x) = Ae^-x + Be^x$ for certain constants $A$ and $B$; (ii) A "constant that depends on a parameter $y$" is the same thing as "a function of $y$"?